# Success method is not called when partialView is returned from Action method

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

The form:

```
<form onsubmit="groupSubmitForm(this)" method="post" action="/Controller/Action">
```

The form is sent to a asp.net MVC action that returns a partialView.

```
function groupSubmitForm(form)
{

alert("test");

form.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $(form).attr('action'),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'html',
    data: $(form).serialize(),       
    success: function (response) {

        alert("success");


    }
           }
});

return false;
    alert("test");

}
```

The post is received ok at controller action, but for some reason the success method is not called when the action returns the partialview.
I'm using an almost identical code piece in the same application that works fine. The The only difference is that the form is submitted from a twitter bootstrap modal.

Does anybody know why neither success or error is executed?

**Update:**

It seams the submit is not really stoped the way I try to do it and that's what's causing the problem. How can I stop the submit event?

**Solution**

Like I wrote in the update the problem was that preventDefault was not working, groupSubmitForm(form, event), event.preventDefault  solved it.

Comment: what is the console error?

Comment: Have you verified now errors occur on the server side?

Comment: no errors on server side, the html is returned to browser but without Calling success first.

Comment: in firefox: ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Answer (score 0):

It seems you haven't add the JQUERY library

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: how come the form is sent to server then?

Comment: @MikeAlike234 The form is going to ignore the broken JavaScript and execute the default action via the default method...